# What is the expected time for the ante to visit all the 8 vertices?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, markov-chains, expected-value

The following is an interview question.

> There is an ante sitting on a vertex of a cube, at each time step, there is $\frac{1}{3}$ probability for the ante to move an each adjacent vertex. What is the expected time for the ante to visit all the 8 vertices?

Let $X$ be the time for the ante to visit all the $8$ vertices.
Then 
$$E(X) = \sum_{x=1}^\infty x P(X=x).$$
However, I have difficulty calculating $P(X=x).$

Comment: This question was answered here already: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59244/what-is-the-cover-time-of-a-random-walk-on-a-cube

Comment: The question in MO is about expected **minimum** time to travel all vertices. I am not sure whether it coincides with my question above.

Comment: It is the same question. You are asking for the expected value of the time at which all vertices are first visited. Or in other words, the expectation of the minimum $t$ such that all vertices have been visited by step $t$. In probability theory it is known as the cover time, see the references cited on MO.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3028469/expected-value-of-the-number-of-steps-in-a-walk-around-the-rectangle/3028531#3028531) is a similar problem, but in this case, figuring out what the states are is much more difficult.  I can't imagine doing it in an interview.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Actually I am thinking to use expected hitting time of a 2D random walk to solve the problem.

Comment: @saulspatz I can solve the similar problem in your posted link using expected hitting time of a modified symmetric random walk. More precisely, define $X_n\in \{0,1\}$ with equal probability $\frac{1}{2}$, $S_n = X_1+...+X_n$ and  $\tau_4 = \min\{n\geq 1: S_n = 4\}.$ By denoting $E_n = \mathbb{E}[\tau_4 | S_0 = n],$ we have $E_1 = 2+E_2,$ $E_2 = 2+E_3,$ $E_3 = 2 + E_4$ and $E_4 = 0.$ Solving them leads to $E_1 = 6,$ which is the same answer there.

Comment: What do you mean by, "as random has binary movements only?"

Comment: @saulspatz However, similar technique does not work here as random walk has binary movements only.

Comment: You're just repeating what you said before, and  it doesn't make sense.  They're both Markov chains.  It's the same technique.